# How to find complement of a expression using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a expression

```
X>Y && Z<=Y
```

I want complement of the expression(`X>Y && Z<=Y`)

```
X<=Y || Z>Y
```

Is it possible to get above output using sympy in python?Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> X, Y, Z = symbols('X Y Z')
>>> simplify(Not(And(X > Y, Z <= Y)))
Or(X <= Y, Z > Y)
```

You can also use `&` and `|` for And and Or, and `~` for Not, but be aware that the precedence is such that you need to parenthesize the terms, like `(X > Y) & (Z <= Y)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its really helpful